# apply a custom function on grouped dataframe n rows at a time

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

A user defined function

```
  CollageImage <- function(path, country, strain, assay,subgroup) {
  img_out <- magick::image_read(path) %>%
    magick::image_trim() %>%
    magick::image_convert(format = "jpeg") %>%
    magick::image_montage(
      tile = tile,
      geometry = paste(500, "x", 500, "+5+5", sep = "")
    ) %>%
    magick::image_border(geometry = "10x80", color = "#FFFFFF") %>%
    magick::image_annotate(
      paste(country, "\n", strain,
            sep = " "
      ),
      weight = 700,
      size = 30,
      location = "+0+0",
      gravity = "north"
    ) %>%
    magick::image_convert("jpg")
  
  #' write the image to file
  img_out %>%
    magick::image_write(
      format = "jpeg",
      path = here::here(paste(country, strain, assay,subgroup, "collage.jpg", sep = "_")),
      quality = 100,
      density = 300
    )
  #' check the collage info
  magick::image_info(img_out)
}
```

grouped data frame

```
out_df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(country ,strain)
```

group map to apply function on the grouped dataframe

```
out_df %>% 
  dplyr::group_map( ~ CollageEachGroup(
  path = .x$path,
  country = .y$country,
  assay = .x$assay,
  strain = .y$strain,
  subgroup
))
```

I would like to apply the function by a moving window of 10 rows at a time within each group. Appreciate any inputs on how to do this. For example, if there are 19 images in a group I would like write 2 files. 1 would be a collage of 10 files and other would be collage of 9 files. And, the files names have to be `A_UK_19_1.csv` and `A_UK_19_2.csv`

This is one way I was thinking to solve it (from So answers), but this is not an elegant way.

```
- Filter each group put
- create a block for each group as follows

    df_subset$bloc <-
      rep(seq(1, 1 + nrow(df_subset) %/% bloc_len), each = bloc_len, length.out = nrow(df_subset))


dput(df)
structure(list(png_file = c("A_UK_1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", "A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", "A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", "A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", "A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", "A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.9.1_lp21_yun7__1.png", "B_UK_2.12.1_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.12.2_lp21_yun7__1.png", "B_UK_2.7.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.7.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "B_UK_2.7.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.9.2_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.5.4_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
"A_UK_2.5.4_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "A_UK_2.6.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
"B_UK_2.5.3_lp21_yun7__1.png", "A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png"), 
    path = c("C:/path/A_UK_1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.9.1_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.12.1_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.12.2_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.7.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.7.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.7.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/B_UK_2.9.2_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.5.4_lp21_pmn1__1.png", 
    "C:/path/A_UK_2.5.4_xno9_pmn1__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.6.4_lp21_yun7__1.png", 
    "C:/path/B_UK_2.5.3_lp21_yun7__1.png", "C:/path/A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png"
    ), assay = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A"), country = c("UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
    "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"
    ), strain = c("Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", 
    "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", 
    "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", 
    "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", "Covid_123", 
    "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", 
    "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", 
    "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", "Covid_125", 
    "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", 
    "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", 
    "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_127", 
    "Covid_127", "Covid_127", "Covid_128")), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(png_file = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), path = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), assay = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), strain = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In the example you give at the end of your post, you mention groups of 10 rows, so why are 19 rows not cut in 10+9 instead of 12+7 as you suggest?

Comment: @Waldi my bad, its 10 + 9. updated Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `slider::slide` to [create subgroups](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slider/vignettes/slider.html) :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(slider)

N <- 10

Collage <- function(country,strain,subgroupnumber,data) {
  cat(paste('Processing:',country,'-',strain,'/',subgroupnumber),'\n')
  cat(paste(nrow(data) , ' files to read \n'))
  cat(paste(data$png_file,collapse=' ; '),'\n')
  cat('\n')
}

res <- df %>% group_by(country,strain) %>% 
  group_walk(~{
    group <- .y
    subgroups <- slider::slide(.x,.f=~.x,.step = N ,.after = N-1)
    # Remove empty elements
    subgroups <- subgroups[lengths(subgroups) != 0]
    
    # Run wished function on each subgroup
    subgroups %>% iwalk(~{
      Collage(group[1],group[2],.y,.x)
  })

})

Processing: UK - Covid_123 / 1 
10  files to read 
A_UK_1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_123 / 2 
9  files to read 
A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_125 / 1 
10  files to read 
A_UK_2.14.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.14.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.8.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_125 / 2 
5  files to read 
A_UK_2.8.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.2_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.14.2_xno9_pmn1__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_127 / 1 
10  files to read 
A_UK_2.2_lp21_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.2_xno9_zn78__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.3_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; A_UK_2.9.1_lp21_yun7__1.png ; B_UK_2.12.1_lp21_yun7__1.png ; B_UK_2.12.2_lp21_yun7__1.png ; B_UK_2.7.1_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; B_UK_2.7.1_xno9_pmn1__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_127 / 2 
7  files to read 
B_UK_2.7.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; B_UK_2.9.2_lp21_yun7__1.png ; A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; A_UK_2.5.4_lp21_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.5.4_xno9_pmn1__1.png ; A_UK_2.6.4_lp21_yun7__1.png ; B_UK_2.5.3_lp21_yun7__1.png 

Processing: UK - Covid_128 / 1 
1  files to read 
A_UK_2.4_lp21_yun7__1.png 
              1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error when I try to pass the column names, in this case `Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: country.. Error in file(con, "wb") : invalid description' argument.` For example, to name the csv file, I would like to pass the column names, and in case of subgroups the group as well. file name would be RTPCR_UK_15_1.csv RTPCR_UK_15_2.csv

Comment: My understanding was that the filename should depend on the `group_by` variables, `country` and `strain` which are stored in `group[1]`and `group[2]`. What should be the content of the file? I thought it would be a subgroup of `df`. How can you be sure that `assay_type` is the same within a subgroup? Should it also be a `group_by` field?

Comment: Sorry, I guess its my mistake not to post the complete example. I thought write the file is the end goal so any function would work. But, looks like that is not possible. I constantly get this error `Error in file(con, "wb") : invalid 'description' argument`. If there is only 1 file in the group your code works, but if there are multiple files that need to be collaged into 1 file it throws the above error. I notice that `iwalk` is on list of file, while group_map took a group files. would you able to modify your answer to fit updated Q and the function ?

Comment: `group_map` + `imap` provides 3 inputs for `Collage` : 2 `group_by` variables `country` and `strain` and a subgrouped dataframe containing between 1-10 rows with the rest of the variables. You don't need to pass `assay` and `path` explicitely to the group function `Collage` because they are already in the subgrouped dataframe : `.x$assay`, `.x$path`, ... Then you should loops over the dataframe in `Collage` to process each row.

Comment: See my edit to illustrate my previous comment. Does it answer your question "apply a custom function on grouped dataframe n rows at a time"?

Comment: Thank you very much